# Code refactoring: from $ to [[

Tags: r, list, rstudio, filemaker, textwrangler

I have a lot of code which uses the `$` operator rather than `[[`. I've read about many advantages of `[[` and would like to refactor all of the code.

Would there be any problems with the following method? And how could I best do the search and replace with RStudio or TextWrangler on a Mac?

```
l <- list()
l$`__a` <- data.frame(`__ID` = stringi::stri_rand_strings(10, 1), col = stringi::stri_rand_strings(10, 1), check.names = F )
```

The code looks like this now:

```
l$`__a`$`__ID`
```

And I would like to refactor it to:

```
l[["__a"]][["__ID"]]
```

To achieve this, are the following replacements sufficient?

```
$` to [["

` to "]]
```

I've found one area in my code where this method would not work, and now I've also found a workaround for how to avoid the issue: [Avoiding backtick characters with dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40151740/avoiding-backtick-characters-with-dplyr)

```
df <- dat[["__Table"]] %>% select(`__ID` ) %>% mutate(fk_table = "__Table", val = 1)
```

Before doing the replacements above, I would need to change the `select` function to this to avoid making false replacements of the backtick character:

```
select_(as.name("__ID"))
```

Unfortunately, the `__` in column names cannot be avoided since the data is downloaded from a relational database (FileMaker) and needs to be written back to the database while preserving the column names.

References about `[[`:

- [Code autocompletion with lists in RStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40126143/code-autocompletion-with-lists-in-rstudio)
- [Is it possible to index an R list using a character variable and the '$' operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30930318/is-it-possible-to-index-an-r-list-using-a-character-variable-and-the-operato)
- [The difference between [] and [[]] notations for accessing the elements of a list or dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/in-r-what-is-the-difference-between-the-and-notations-for-accessing-the)

References about refactoring in R:

- [R language aware code reformatting/refactoring tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9105357/r-language-aware-code-reformatting-refactoring-tools)
- [Tips for refactoring repetitive code in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25650880/tips-for-refactoring-repetitive-code-in-r)

Comment: Honestly, I wouldn't worry too much about refactoring your code.  You're probably going to introduce more errors in refactoring than you are likely to experience by leaving it.  I just spent 20 minutes trying to get a start and the best I can come up with comes no where near functioning on all of the common cases, let alone the edge cases.  `library(stringr)
test <- c("x <- df$var_name\n",
          "x <- df$var_name",
          "x <- df$var_name ")
str_replace(test, 
            pattern = "([$])(.+)(\n|[!\"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@^\`{|}~])", 
            replace = "[[\"\\2\"]]\\3")`

Comment: I second @Benjamin's comment. Fix only important things in existing code and use your newfound fav idiom moving forward. Your `$`-filled code is not wrong and not broken. Spend your limited resource of time on new and important things.

Comment: Thanks @Benjamin and @hrbmstr, I appreciate your comments. Here, the purpose of refactoring is only part of the story and not only for code readability. Actually I prefer `$` for readability even though it has the backtick symbols. My main goals is to allow for passing column names as variables (even when they start with `_` and that is easier with standard strings that don't contain backtick symbols.) Does that make sense? Now the parts that have backticks are hard coded and I will move towards calculating them dynamically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try:

```
v <- c("l$`__a`$`__ID`")

library(stringi)
stri_replace_all_fixed(v, c('$`', '`'), c('[["', '"]]'), vectorize_all = FALSE)
```

Which gives:

```
#[1] "l[[\"__a\"]][[\"__ID\"]]"
```

**Note:** You see the `\"` in the output because `print()` escapes the quotes when diplaying them. You can wrap the above in `noquote()` to see the output without the `\"`

```
noquote(
  stri_replace_all_fixed(v, c('$`', '`'), c('[["', '"]]'), vectorize_all = FALSE)
)
```

Which gives:

```
#[1] l[["__a"]][["__ID"]]
```

---

Should you want to apply this on an entire file, you could try:

```
writeLines(stri_replace_all_fixed(readLines("script.R"), 
                                  c('$`', '`'), c('[["', '"]]'), vectorize_all = FALSE),
           file("new_script.R"))
```

Comment: This looks very encouraging. Do you know how to apply it to an entire .r file?

Comment: @Bobby Maybe `stri_replace_all_fixed(readLines("script.R"), c('$`', '`'), c("[['", "']]"), vectorize_all = FALSE)` ?

Comment: I still think this is a fantastic answer for the specific part of my question. For the general part, I'm not yet sure. How can I make sure that I don't have backtick symbols which should not be replaced?

Comment: @Bobby I'm thinking we could use a more robust approach with a regex to make sure we only change the backtick if there were a  `$backtick` before.